# Do I need to worry about different contexts in NSNotification Observers

Tags: ios, objective-c, observer-pattern

I have a class that is observing when a new object 'Product' gets created so it can update details in a 'User' object.

When I save my Product object, I do it in a method on a background thread which issues the Notification that a new object has been created. I set the object in the notification's userInfo.

The observer fires when the notification is posted. I need to save some data so I create a new save block which in turn creates a new NSManagedObjectContext. I **ASSUME** I have to get the object in this new context.

Unfortunately, when I try to fetch the record from the new context, it returns an object with empty details. However, the object that came from the notification's userInfo is fully populated.

Am I correct in assuming I need to re-fetch the record? Is the re-fetched record empty possibly because the save isn't complete yet?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for the fetch?

Answer (score 0):

The notification our talking about is the CoreData generated when saveContext is done ? (NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification).

In this case, when you receive the notification you must manually merge the context with

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [_managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
```

});

So the context that has saved the changes in the Product entity merges his changes to other contexts.

Hope it helps.